# SSH Permission denied(public key,password)

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two Linux machine one is consider as master(192.168.8.70) another one is slave(192.168.8.161). In both machine i installed openssh server.And i create an `RSA key pair` in both linux machine with an empty password using this linux command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""` . And i copied master machine public key and paste into slave machine authorized_keys file and vice versa. Also i changed both machine hosts( from this path `/etc/hosts`) file like below

```
192.168.8.70    master  (IP address of the master)
192.168.8.161   slave   (IP address of the slave)
```

Now i am trying to connect from master to slave using this command  `hduser@master:$ ssh slave` that time it shows the error in linux terminal `Permission denied(publickey,password)`

but in my slave machine `var/log/auth.log` file shows the error like

```
slave sshd[3754]: Invalid user hduser from 192.168.8.170
slave sshd[3754]: input_userauth_request: invalid user hduser [preauth]
```

i don't know what i missed or what's the problem please give some solution..

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your username is different, you need to specify it `ssh username@slave`

Comment: thanks for reply. master machine username is hduser and slave machine  username is hduserslave. but when we connect `ssh hduserslave@slave` is connecting successfully. But can i connect only using hostname like `ssh slave` from master machine. of course it is possible but i don't know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a remote host without having to specify the remote
username, you can create / add an entry to your local user’s SSH
configuration in `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote.hostname
    User remote_username
```

Adding this allows you to connect using `ssh remote.hostname`.

In your case, the configuration setting would be something like:

```
Host slave
    User hduserslave
```

Other SSH configuration settings are documented in the manual page, `man ssh_config`.

Comment: i don't have such `config` file from this path `$HOME/.ssh/config` but i have file path in `etc/ssh/ssh_config`. so can i change from this path `etc/ssh/ssh_config` like you mention `Host slave
    User hduserslave`

Comment: It's best practice to create your own personal configuration file (if it doesn't already exist) but if you're the only user for that machine, you should be OK using the system configuration file in `/etc`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution it is working fine.
But when i connect `masterusername@slaveip(my case hduser@192.168.8.161)  or masterusername@slavehostname(my case hduser@slave)`  that time it is asking password even if i give password it shows error in linux terminal `permission denied` but in `var/log/auth.log` file shows the error like below
    
        `slave sshd[3754]: Invalid user hduser from 192.168.8.170
        slave sshd[3754]: input_userauth_request: invalid user hduser [preauth]`  
    need any configuration for connecting like above?

Comment: When you connect using `hduser@slave`, you’re explicitly telling SSH that you want to connect to the `hduser` account on the `slave` host (overriding any configured default username) but `hduser` is not a valid user for `slave`.

Comment: @senthil I'm glad that the solution worked for you so it’d be good if you accepted this answer (see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716)). Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!